# Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 fan runs full speed after resume from suspend and then reboots

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, suspend, fan, restart

I've recently clean installed Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome version on my ThinkPad Edge e540. Since then I have a problem with resuming from suspend. When I resume and get the login screen fan immediately starts running on max speed and when I enter the password I have normal screen and everything working fine for about 10 seconds (fan is still on max speed) and then it just reboots the whole system.

My kernel version is 4.10.0-32-generic and I'm using Noveau display driver (e540 has Nvidia GT 740m graphich card).

Any solutions/advices for this problem?

Comment: Install the recommend Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Thank you, I switched to nvidia 375.66 driver and haven't had any issues last 24 hours.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue on my E540 with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04. How do you install the nvidia driver?

Comment: I switched now to the integrated graphics and haven't had any issues, yet.